# Libreswan to Juniper. The tunnel is not going up

Tags: ipsec, proxmox, juniper, libreswan

authentication-method pre-shared-keys
dh-group group14
authentication-algorithm sha1
encryption-algorithm aes-256-cbc
lifetime-seconds 28800

protocol esp
authentication-algorithm hmac-sha1-96
encryption-algorithm aes-256-cbc
lifetime-seconds 3600

Error that occurs:
<right_ip_address>:500: initial Main Mode message received but no connection has been authorized with policy PSK
We most likely do not get answers because of problems with the first phase (PSK - I checked it), which is exactly what the error says about:
initial Main Mode message received but no connection has been authorized with policy PSK.
Has anyone experienced this?